# Variables as matrix in Equation in Rmarkdown

Tags: matrix, dynamic, r-markdown

I have an assignment where I needed to calculate the covariance matrix step by step. I did it in R. I am displaying the results via Rmarkdown like shown below. However, I do have to enter numbers over and over again. Is there some way to insert data frames as matrices into the equations? I was only able to find solutions were data frames were displayed as single tables/matrices, but not within a formula.
here is the formula as it is displayed in Rmarkdown and the code below:
[formula](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%24%24%5Chat%7Bs%7D%5E2_%7B1%2C2%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B5%7D%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E5%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D%209-6%5C%5C%202-6%5C%5C%206-6%5C%5C%205-6%5C%5C%208-6%5C%5C%20%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%20%5Ctimes%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D%2012-8%5C%5C%208-8%5C%5C%206-8%5C%5C%204-8%5C%5C%2010-8%5C%5C%20%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B5%7D%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E5%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D%203%5C%5C%20-4%5C%5C%200%5C%5C%20-1%5C%5C%202%5C%5C%20%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%20%5Ctimes%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D%204%5C%5C%200%5C%5C%20-2%5C%5C%20-4%5C%5C%202%5C%5C%20%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%20%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B5%7D%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E5%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D%2012%5C%5C%200%5C%5C%200%5C%5C%204%5C%5C%204%5C%5C%20%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%20%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B5%7D%5Ctimes%2020%24%24%20%24%24%5Chat%7Bs%7D%5E2_%7B1%2C2%7D%3D4%24%24)

```
`$$\hat{s}^2_{1,2}=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{j=1}^5
\begin{pmatrix}
9-6\\
2-6\\
6-6\\
5-6\\
8-6\\
\end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
12-8\\
8-8\\
6-8\\
4-8\\
10-8\\
\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{j=1}^5
\begin{pmatrix}
3\\
-4\\
0\\
-1\\
2\\
\end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
4\\
0\\
-2\\
-4\\
2\\
\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{j=1}^5
\begin{pmatrix}
12\\
0\\
0\\
4\\
4\\
\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{1}{5}\times 20$$
$$\hat{s}^2_{1,2}=4$$`


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfNIZ.gif
```